# Failed to call `pp::FileChooser_Dev` in NaCl

Tags: google-nativeclient, ppapi

I need to write a file uploader PPAPI plugin instead of using NPAPI in Chrome.

I extend the `hello_nacl_cpp` project in `vs_addin` example to test PPAPI and NaCl. The code is similar to this:

```
...

int32_t showSelectFileDialog() {
    pp::CompletionCallbackWithOutput< std::vector<pp::FileRef> > cb =
        factory_.NewCallbackWithOutput(&NaClProjectInstance::onFilesSelected);

    int32_t ret = file_chooser_.Show(cb);

    return ret;
}

void onFilesSelected(int32_t result,
                     const std::vector<pp::FileRef>& files) {
    std::stringstream ss;

    if (result == PP_OK) {
        // ok
    } else {
        ss << "undo select file? error code: " << result;

        PostMessage(pp::Var(ss.str()));
    }
}
...
```

It's ok if I select PPAPI platform and debug above code. But on NaCl64 platform, the result is `PP_ERROR_NO_USER_GESTURE(-41)`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

/**
   * This value indicates failure due to lack of a user gesture such as a
   * mouse click or key input event. Examples of actions requiring a user
   * gesture are showing the file chooser dialog and going into fullscreen
   * mode.
   */
  PP_ERROR_NO_USER_GESTURE = -41,

call showSelectFileDialog() in HandleInputEvent